# Get PS1 evaluated value, or shell prompt value

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to find the command that would return me evaluated value of $PS1 variable or just shell prompt with current path.

e.g.

```
foo-user@bar-pc:~\bar
```

I would like to avoid using something like, since pwd will not truncate home_dir as `~`.

```
echo "`whoami`@`hostname`:`pwd`"
```

Comment: why is this bad question? to who ever hated.

Comment: A hack that I am too lazy to complete: run a real shell and find someway to make it believe the input is a tty.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060500/bash-how-to-evaluate-ps1-ps2

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of billc.cn‘s suggestion:

```
        $(export PS1; echo exit | sh -i 2>&1)
```

Of course, if you have `!` in `PS1`, it will be evaluated as “1” — unless you have some sort of history saving going on.  User name, hostname, current directory, date & time, etc., should be OK.